# How a WireShark is Knowing saved Pcap files includes FCS or not?

Tags: wireshark, sniffer

I am using a wireshark. I sniffed packets with FCS using wireshark and saved into pcap file in HardDisk. At the running time it can know FCS is included or not. But my doubt is, when I open a saved pcap file using wireshark how it is knowing whether the saved file is captured with FCS or not?
How wireshark is differentiating files with FCS?
Is there any variable in pcap file to know this?

Answer (score 1):

> when I open a saved pcap file using wireshark how it is knowing whether the saved file is captured with FCS or not?

It *doesn't* know.  It *guesses*, based on:

- how long the actual packet being sent over Ethernet is (for example, IPv4 packets have a "total length" field);
- how long the Ethernet packet is (it may be longer than needed for the actual packet, as Ethernet packets must be at least 64 octets long, including the Ethernet header, the Ethernet payload, and the FCS).

If the Ethernet packet looks as if it's 4 octets longer than it would be *without* the FCS, Wireshark assumes those 4 octets are the FCS.

> How wireshark is differentiating files with FCS?

Some file formats always include the FCS, some file formats never include the FCS, and some file formats, such as pcap, might or might not include the FCS.  The code that handles different capture file formats indicates that to the code in Wireshark that actually read the files.

> Is there any variable in pcap file to know this?

Unfortunately, no, there isn't, which is why Wireshark has to guess.

> In case of 802.11 there exists a Management packets, we can't know the exact length of Packets because there exists Information elements which are of variable length. In that case how Wireshark guess the FCS?

It doesn't.

For 802.11, just as for Ethernet, some file formats always include the FCS, some file formats never include the FCS, and some file formats, such as pcap, might or might not include the FCS.  The code that handles different capture file formats indicates that to the code in Wireshark that actually read the files.

For file formats that might or might not include the FCS:

- if the packets don't have a [radiotap](http://www.radiotap.org) metadata header before the 802.11 header, Wireshark checks a preference that the *user* has to set (you can't indicate it in the file);
- if the packets *do* have a radiotap header, and it includes a [Flags](http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/Flags) field, Wireshark checks the "frame includes FCS" flag in that field.

Comment: Thank for Response ...In case of 802.11 there exists a Management packets, we can't know the exact length of  Packets  because there exists Information elements which are of variable length. In that case how Wireshark guess the FCS?